# Clear all array list data

Tags: c#

Why doesn't the code below clear all array list data?

```
        Console.WriteLine("Before cleaning:" + Convert.ToString(ID.Count));
        //ID.Count = 20
        for (int i = 0; i < ID.Count; i++)
        {
            ID.RemoveAt(i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("After cleaning:" + Convert.ToString(ID.Count));
        //ID.Count = 10
```

Why is 10 printed to the screen?

Maybe there is another special function, which deletes everything?

Comment: The first time through the loop you remove the item at position 0. There are now 19 items in the list, the item at position 1 now moves to position zero, 2 -> 1, 3->2 etc. The second time through the loop you remove the item at position 1 (this used to be item 2). You have skipped the item at position 0 (that used to be item 1). In this way you are removing every second item from the list.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
`Array.Clear()`
```

removes all items in the array.

```
`Array.RemoveAt(i)`
```

removes the element of ith index in the array.

Answer (score 12):

You're only actually calling `RemoveAt` 10 times. When `i` reaches 10, `ID.Count` will be 10 as well. You *could* fix this by doing:

```
int count = ID.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < originalCount; i++)
{
    ID.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

This is an O(n<sup>2</sup>) operation though, as removing an entry from the start of the list involves copying everything else.

More efficiently (O(n)):

```
int count = ID.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < originalCount; i++)
{
    ID.RemoveAt(ID.Count - 1);
}
```

or equivalent but simpler:

```
while (ID.Count > 0)
{
    ID.RemoveAt(ID.Count - 1);
}
```

But using `ID.Clear()` is probably more efficient than all of these, even though it is also O(n).

Answer (score 6):

```
ArrayList.Clear Method
Removes all elements from the ArrayList.
```

for more detail : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.clear.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use the clear() Method

or

change `ID.RemoveAt(i);` to `ID.RemoveAt(0);`

Whenever an element is removed from the collection, its index also changes. Hence when you say `ID.RemoveAt(0);` the element at index 1 now will be moved to index 0. So again you've to remove the same element (like dequeuing). until you reach the last element. However if you want to remove all the elements at once you can better use the Clear() method.

Answer (score 2):

After removing 10 items, `ID.Count() == 10` and `i == 10` so the loop stops.

Use [`ID.Clear()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.clear.aspx) to remove all items in the array list.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does:

```
ID.RemoveAt(0);
...
ID.RemoveAt(9);
ID.RemoveAt(10); \\ at this point you have already removed 10 
                 \\ items so there is nothing left on 10- 19, but you are left with 
                 \\ the 'first' 10 elements
...
ID.RemoveAt(19);
```

Generally speaking your method removes every second element from the list..

Use [`ArrayList.Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.clear.aspx) instead as other have mentioned.